# Google Charts show just one entry of MySQL when connected?

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization, data-visualization

I have the following `Google Charts` code and I'm trying to connect it with `MySQL`, I have tried each and everything with it available on the internet but it still shows just one entry of SQL result set, although I have 10 entries in it. On the internet I found the `$row_num` counter thing and since including it in my code, I have been able to query one entry but I want to query all entries with it. Please help me with this and let me know what mistake (if any) I have been making, Following is my PHP code:

```
    [<?php

``$dbhandle= new mysqli('localhost','root','8317','record');
//echo $dbhandle->connect_error();

$query= "SELECT * from  download_manager";
$res= $dbhandle->query($query);
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':\['bar'\]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

      function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(\[
          \['Title', 'No. of Downloads'\],
          <?php
          $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
          $row_num = 0;
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
{

  $row_num++;

  if ($row_num == $total_rows){
    echo "\['".$row\['filename'\]."',".$row\['downloads'\]."\]";
}

}
}
else
{
    echo "0 results";
}
          ?>
        \]);

        var options = {
          width: 800,
          chart: {
            'title': 'Top 10 Downloads',
            subtitle: 'for the last month'
          },
          bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          axes: {
          }
        };

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_x_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    See Also : <a href="barchart1.html"> Downloads in the Last 7 Years </a> <br> <br>

    <div id="dual_x_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed adding a comma `,` in your PHP data loop. Try with the following:

```
echo "\['".$row\['filename'\]."',".$row\['downloads'\]."\],";
```